# How to free variables in tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

It seems that memory are allocated for a variable only after running its initializer in a session.
For some reason, I have to use some temporary variables. For example there isn't enough memory to run a big batch at one time, so I need to store the temporary gradients in extra variables. When I don't need this variables anymore, I want to make it at the uninitialized state (the state that no memory is allocated for it). Cause there is no memory for other computations. 
The method I use now is to initialize variable in a session, then close this session and create a new session, where I have to fetch the persistent variables value in python ndarray( cpu memory),and initialize those variable in the new session, which is verbose. 
So I'd like to know is there any method to free a variable in tensorflow.